# Xamarin Forms with Firebase. Data retrival throwing System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.forms

[image]

```
 public async Task<IEnumerable<Users>> GetAllUsers()
        {
               return (await firebase
              .Child("Users")
              .OnceAsync<Users>()).Select(item => new Users
              {
                  UserName= item.Object.UserName.ToString(),
                  Password = item.Object.Password.ToString(),
                  Role  = item.Object.Role.ToString()
              }).ToList();
        }
```

I am a beginner to App development. While retriving the data from the Firebase Realtime database getting the above error. Scratching head for 4 hours. Please help.

Comment: What does your Users collection look like on firebase?

Comment: @Woj https://console.firebase.google.com/project/login-bbea5/database/login-bbea5/data

Comment: I won't be able to see your project, take a screenshot of it.

Comment: @Woj pls check now.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to cast it toString(). Firebase casts types on its own, when you push that object on Firebase Realtime database, it will automatically assign correct type when you pull it back.Get rid of the ToString() on each property and see if that fixes the issue.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Users>> GetAllUsers()
    {
           return (await firebase
          .Child("Users")
          .OnceAsync<Users>()).Select(item => new Users
          {
              UserName= item.Object.UserName,
              Password = item.Object.Password,
              Role  = item.Object.Role
          }).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: First i tried without casting only. Later i tried with casting. Both are not working

Comment: The only reason why this is not working, is that you have pushed completely different object Type to what are you trying to pull back. Like I mentioned in comment above, add screenshot of your Users collection in original question. and probably you wanna show the method  that also pushes Users Object to firebase.